# Check for different roots in transformation

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have the following xslt sheet and I am wondering if its possible to check for a certain root in an xml file? If so what is the correct xslt code needed in order to transform the xml to use a certain template? I tried with stylesheet below that I built but this threw an error complaining about invalid root. As you can make out from this stylesheet if I have a certain root in an xml file I would like to apply a certain template to it. What do you all think?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Envelope">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Payload" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Request1">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Payload"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Request2">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Payload2"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Payload" >
 <soap12:Envelope >
  <soap12:Body>
    <Method1>
      <xdocPayload>
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xdocPayload>
    </Method1>
    </soap12:Body>
  </soap12:Envelope>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="Payload2" >
  <soap12:Envelope>
    <soap12:Body>
      <Method2>
       <xdocPayload>
         <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xdocPayload>
      </Method2>
   </soap12:Body>
 </soap12:Envelope>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

c# Code i'm testing with:

```
  XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform(true);

  xslt.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsltTransSheet)));
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
DND

2 different XML Input Files:

```
 <Envelope>
     <order>1280</order>
 </Envelope>
```

or could be

```
 <Request1>
    <item>7329HH</item>
 <Request1>
```

Desired XML Output:

```
<soap12:Body>
            <Method1>
                <xdocPayload>
                   <Envelope>
                     <order>1280</order>
                   </Envelope>
                </xdocPayload>
             </Method1>
 </soap12:Body>
```

or the XML Ouput would end up being

```
  <soap12:Body>
            <Method1>
                <xdocPayload>
                   <Request1>
                      <item>7329HH</item>
                   </Request1>
                </xdocPayload>
             </Method1>
  </soap12:Body>
```

I'm looking for one or the other result depending on xml fed into xslt. Hopefully that explains it a little more thoroughly.

Comment: None of the provided XML files has a top element named `Envelope`, `Request1` or `Request2`. Please, edit your question and finally provide correct data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a `soap12` namespace prefix in your output. You should declare this in the root of your stylesheet, like so:

```
<xsl:stylesheet ... xmlns:soap12="someuri" ...>
```

It's also possible that the stylesheet doesn't actually output anything if the input root can't be matched against any template, or outputs an invalid XML file. The latter could be the case if you've got both a `Payload` and `Payload2` element in your XML somewhere, but its root element doesn't match any template.

You might want to consider using named templates and calling those, instead of using `apply-templates` with something that might also match out of context. Or use template modes to make sure you're only using a template from within another one.

EDIT: take a look at this XML...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
    <Payload/>
    <Payload2/>
</test>
```

Applying your stylesheet to it (with corrected `soap12` declaration) would yield the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap12:Body>
        <Method1>
            <xdocPayload>
                <Payload/>
            </xdocPayload>
        </Method1>
    </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap12:Body>
        <Method2>
            <xdocPayload>
                <Payload2/>
            </xdocPayload>
        </Method2>
    </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

That ain't valid XML since there's two root elements, which isn't allowed.

Here's a suggested reworking of your stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Envelope" priority="2">
        <soap12:Envelope>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Payload"/>
        </soap12:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/Request1" priority="2">
        <soap12:Envelope>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Payload"/>
        </soap12:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/Request2" priority="2">
        <soap12:Envelope>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Payload2"/>
        </soap12:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*" priority="1">
        <soap12:Envelope />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Payload">
            <soap12:Body>
                <Method1>
                    <xdocPayload>
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                        </xsl:copy>
                    </xdocPayload>
                </Method1>
            </soap12:Body>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Payload2">
            <soap12:Body>
                <Method2>
                    <xdocPayload>
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                        </xsl:copy>
                    </xdocPayload>
                </Method2>
            </soap12:Body>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Mind that I don't have a full picture of your input or desired output, so don't simply take the above literally but look at what it does and correct according to your own requirements.

**EDIT 2:** okay, after you've added the samples it's clearer what you want to do. You'll need to simply call named templates, like I suggested earlier. Here's a basis to get started from. Adapt as you see fit, make sure you test various input cases. Find an editor program somewhere that let's you quickly try out or even debug XSLT, it'll help a great deal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Envelope" priority="2">
        <soap12:Envelope>
            <xsl:call-template name="Payload"/>
        </soap12:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/Request1" priority="2">
        <soap12:Envelope>
             <xsl:call-template name="Payload"/>
        </soap12:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/Request2" priority="2">
        <soap12:Envelope>
             <xsl:call-template name="Payload2"/>
        </soap12:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*" priority="1">
        <soap12:Envelope />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="Payload">
            <soap12:Body>
                <Method1>
                    <xdocPayload>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                    </xdocPayload>
                </Method1>
            </soap12:Body>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="Payload2">
            <soap12:Body>
                <Method2>
                    <xdocPayload>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                    </xdocPayload>
                </Method2>
            </soap12:Body>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: G_H - What I'm attempting to do is if a certain XML file that has a root of Envelope then apply a certain template and if the root is something else and theirs a match then apply some other template. What am I doing wrong in my above xslt sheet? DND

Comment: @DotNetDude I understood your intent from the stylesheet. Your approach is correct, but like I said, you'll need to fix that namespace prefix declaration first and make sure you're not accidentally matching the wrong stuff. I'll add in some suggested changes in a moment...

Comment: G_H - Ok look at the edit in orig post for desired output. As you can see I only want one template result. Also looking at your xslt sheet it seems like it will first accept any valid root and just apply the soap envelope, correct?

Comment: G_H - Updated my original post to include XML samples and output. Any ideas?

Comment: @DotNetDude You're welcome. But make sure to learn why and how it works so you don't run into surprises for any use cases I might not have seen.